# In texture paint mode the Accumulate mode only works in the image editor window, not on the mesh itself

Tags: texture-painting, uv-image-editor

I included my node setup for the material I'm painting on.  It is strange, but when I paint directly on the mesh my black paint shows up only as a light tint that never gets any darker unless I release the pointer and reapply more paint on top.  If I do this about 8 times I get a very black color.  On the Image Editor window, however, I can keep the pointer pressed down and just scribble back and forth and the paint accumulates correctly making a darker and darker area without having to release and reapply and release and reapply several times.  Is this a bug, or more likely I don't really grok texture painting. Can someone assist?

By the way, I tried this on the make-up layer texture as well as the skin texture layer.  Same result.

[image]

Here I show you my current brush settings and in the 3D view window, you can see 3 blue sections on the model's cheek.  The far left one is the result of 4 or 5 passes of the brush (click and hold, scribble scribble scribble, release, repeat), the middle one is the result of scribbling in the editor window, and the far right is the result of scribbling on the model in the 3D window in just one pass (click and hold, scribble scribble scribble, release).  When I have "accumulate" checked, shouldn't I be able to get the middle and left result by doing what I did in the far right example?  Why does it remain so pale no matter how much I scribble over it?  Why am I having to release and reclick to add more paint?[image]

Comment: Can you show a screen shot of your brush settings so I can see what you are doing? You currently have black set up on the brush, but your image painting is in color on a zero alpha image. Also , are you able to see all the image textures in the Slots panel?

Comment: @CraigDJones happy to tonight. This map with the transparent base color is added on top of the skin texture. It’s my “makeup” layer. So I had my brush set to a black color to paint in some eye shadow or eye liner. I’ll post a pic of what the different effect is of applying the brush in the 3D view vs the editor window. As for my brush settings, I take it you’re referring to the Paint toolbar on the bottom left of my pic... you want to see that expanded out, correct?

Comment: It looks like it is working - compare strokes made with accumulate turned off and on side by side, and you will see the difference as far as the strength of the brush. Turn off pressure and test with just the comparison of with and without, and you will see it working.

Comment: @CraigDJones Thanks. But no it isn’t working at all. The light blue area on the mouth and nose is the same color on the first pass as it is on the 100th pass if I don’t release and click again. Whereas the other two darker blue areas are from several passes with only one click (accumulate works) and several passes with multiple clicks (accumulate not working in 3D view)